# Latex TOC page number position all to top center

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, tocstyle

I have one problem with the page number in Table of Content. 
My settings are:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}


\begingroup
%\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{fancy}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{3}
\tableofcontents
 \cleardoublepage
\endgroup

\newpage
\addcontentsline{tableofcontents}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{tableofcontents}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\end{document}
```

But the page number in TOC and List of Figure and tables are like: odd page in the bottom center, and even page in top center. What I want is all page numbers in top center. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here, why it does not work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add `\documentclass{yourclass}` to your code. You can use `tocbibind` package for the addition to the toc and the ToC/LoF/Lot commands use an implicit `\thispagestyle{plain}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes the plain page style globally (since this is applied by `\tableofcontents` etc.)

I additionally removed some strange grouping/unnecessary `\clearpage` commands and added `\usepackage{tocbibind}` for clean addition to ToC

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{page}{3}  %% Why??????
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit** Dotted toc line for `LoF` and `LoT` -- I don't recommend this!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@fakesection{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


\setcounter{page}{3}  %% Why??????
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{fakesection}{\bfseries\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{fakesection}{\bfseries\listtablename}
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian Hupfer ...This really works...you saved me from many days of working....thanks a lot

Comment: @user2307344: If you want to keep the page headings for sections/chapters, we've to reenable them of course. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer , in fact I need this for my whole document. I managed with other parts, the TOC is the only part left. now they are all solved , thanks again

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer Do you know how can I add dot after List of Table and Figures? Also delete the first small contents ..it is not needed here. thanks

Comment: @user2307344: Those are other questions. With dot you mean the dotted line? The ToC can be removed from ToC with the `nottoc` option -- see my edited answer

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer  I mean all sections, chapters and List of Figure, List of Table have.......until the page number...Do you understand?

Comment: @user2307344: Well, I see, but 1st your requesting things not initially in your post and 2nd: It doesn't look nice anyway if you use a dotted toc line, in my point of view

Comment: @user2307344: I've updated with dotted lines

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer .Thanks a lot, it works now